# mp4 video rotation metadata removal

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rotation, metadata

Using ffmpeg to remove rotate metadata works but output is little bit confusing as Metadata: rotate: 90 still appears in output section.

```
ffmpeg version N-92663-g8affd75
```

seems to keep rotate metadata:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid_20190302_162804987.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2019-03-02T15:28:43.000000Z
    com.android.version: 6.0.1
  Duration: 00:00:32.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17230 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17003 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 28.98 fps, 29.33 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-03-02T15:28:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      encoder         : MOTO
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-02T15:28:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Output #0, mp4, to '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    com.android.version: 6.0.1
    encoder         : Lavf58.24.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 17003 kb/s, 28.98 fps, 29.33 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-03-02T15:28:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      encoder         : MOTO
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-02T15:28:43.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

but fortunatly the rotate is missing in succeeding ffmpeg (or ffprobe)

Comment: Can't duplicate the issue, so I'm going to guess you need to update your ffmpeg. Otherwise, show the complete log from your first command and provide the input file if possible.

Comment: Please show the actual command and the **complete** log.

Comment: What do you mean by "missing in succeeding ffmpeg"? missing in output file (but shown in transcoding log output)?

Comment: Using `ffmpeg -i vid_20190302_162804987.mp4  -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -ss 6 -t 19 -c copy 1.mp4`  works perfect, but I was confused by `Output #0, mp4, to '1.mp4': 
 ... 
 Metadata:
      rotate          : 90 
 ... '

Comment: My assumption was that metadata rotate=90 is still within output file. I separated the rotate removal from cutting (-ss/-t) and made a second ffmpeg transformation, and  the rotate was visibly gone. In reality it is already gone after first transformation, it is only the transformation log of first transformation which caused the confusion.